# How to change the redirect url when logging out?

Tags: authentication, redirect, laravel-5

I'm working with Laravel 5 authentification system provided by default.
After logging out, a user is redirected to the root page but I'd like to change that.
I managed to do it for the "login" and "registering" process by defining "$redirectTo" in "AuthController.php". But for "logout", I defined "$redirectAfterLogout" at the same place but it seems to not be taken into account.

Could anyone explain me where is the problem and how to fix it please?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For Laravel 5,

Open `AuthController` class : app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php

Add below property to the class

```
protected $redirectAfterLogout = 'auth/login';
```

you can change `auth/login` with any url.

Comment: That's strange. I already tried that with no success... but when I tried again a few minutes ago, it works. Thank you!

Comment: @kururin Thats because it was just recently added... https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/aa1204448a0d89e2846cbc383ce487df6efd9fc8

Comment: And how can I do this in Laravel 5.3, it doesn't contain AuthController.php

Comment: @SunnyKumar, I was wondering the same.. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @SunnyKumar, I've found a solution, check the answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114406/how-to-logout-and-redirect-to-login-page-using-laravel-5-3

Comment: Apparently, this does not work for Laravel 5.3+ for some reason. The only way is to override the function.

Answer (score 3):

The redirect after logout is hard coded in the trait `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers`. You can override it in your `AuthController` by adding this:

```
public function getLogout()
{
    $this->auth->logout();

    return redirect('logout');
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was my first attempt. It works but I thought there was a better way to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't provide the `$redirectAfterLogout` attribute, it will use the default which is `'/'`.

This logic can be found in this class: `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php`

```
public function logout()
{
    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->logout();

    return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
}
```

Having said that, just add this attribute in your AuthController:

```
protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/afterRedirectURL';
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Laravel 5.5** override logout method inside LoginController. In my case I am redirecting to home route after login.

```
/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using the built in laravel Auth in the controllers I just override the loggedOut method which triggers after logout to redirect

in the "LoginController.php" which uses

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;
```

in the AuthenticatesUsers Trait is a logout method, you can optionally override this or you will see that it triggers a loggedOut method

You can override the logged out method which is default blank and have that redirect

```
    /**
     * The user has logged out of the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function loggedOut()
    {
        return redirect()->route('login.show');
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In App\Controllers\Auth\AuthController, add the following two variables.

```
protected $redirectTo = '/private_dashboard';
protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/public_homepage';
```

You get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

I have a same problem in Laravel 5.0. Override a method does the trick.

1) Go to app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php
2) Add a new method :

```
// Override Logout method (define custom url)
public function getLogout()
{
    $this->auth->logout();
    return redirect('auth/login');  // Your Custom URL
}
```

Answer (score -2):

it'only laravel versi 5.4 if you want custom redirect url logout,
open `/your-project-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php` 
and edit redirect based on you needed

```
  public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

Comment: Vendor files should not be committed or edited. This will break on your next composer update.

Comment: It is actually correct function, but wrong file, in L5.4, you should overwrite this method to Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php