# Laravel redirects to wrong url

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm using Vagrant + Homestead + VirtualBox and Laravel 5.4, middleware redirecting not authenticated users to login page, which is on different url:

```
return redirect()->away(env('APP_LOGIN') . '&logout=true');
```

My .env file:

```
APP_LOGIN=http://login.app/
```

But when redirect happens, it's redirect to

```
http://login.app/://login.app/
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect after logout is hard coded in the trait AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers. You can override it in your AuthController by adding this:

```
public function getLogout()
 {
     $this->auth->logout();

     return redirect('logout');
 }
```

Original answer is given here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29797510/7672311

Comment: I'm using custom Login class, because of using central login app